# Conditional radio re-render not effected with the current state value after i rendered that value once previously?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, state

I already select(Male) this record once previously before i select second record(Female)
*state is updated when select record

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have forgot something or implemented it incorrectly, since you have not provided the code i am attaching it on the assumption that you're using a class component...

```
import React from "react";
export default class RadioButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: 'Male'
    };
}

  radioChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <input type="radio"
               value="Male"
               checked={this.state.selectedOption === "Male"}
               onChange={this.radioChange} />Male

        <input type="radio"
               value="Female"
               checked={this.state.selectedOption === "Female"}
               onChange={this.radioChange}/>Female

        <input type="radio"
               value="Other"
               checked={this.state.selectedOption === "Other"}
               onChange={this.radioChange}/>Other

        <h3>this.state.selectedOption: {this.state.selectedOption}</h3>
      </div> 
    );
  }
}
```

here's the link to [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-archimedes-qu4jq)

Comment: Thank you very much. i used defaultChecked instead of checked.